# How to interpret a Regression Error Characteristic curve

Tags: regression, prediction, accuracy

How can I interpret the REC (Regression Error Characteristic) curve ? What is error tolerance and what is the area over the curve? What should be the accepted value for the error tolerance?

How to interpret, for ex, the following graph.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regression Error Characteristic shows the error level on the X axis and the proportion of points under this error level on the Y axis.

For example, in your graph:

- For X=1, the Y value is around 15-20% for the kNN model. This means that the kNN model predicts around 15-20% of the instances with an error less or equal to 1. By contrast, the Y value is around 30-35% for the SVM model, so the SVM model has a higher proportion of instances with a small error (less or equal 1).
- One can also start with the Y value: for Y=75% of the instances, X is around 1.1-1.2 for both models. So both models predict 75% of the instances with an error less or equal to 1.1-1.2.

Of course, a good system would have the highest possible proportion of instances within the lowest possible level of error, so ideally the curve should be as close as possible to the top left corner.

The area over the curve is all the area between the top left corner and the curve, i.e. on the left and above the curve (as opposed to the area to the right and under the curve). It can be used as a measure of the overall amount of error that the system makes: if this area is small, it means that the system is close to the top left corner so it's good. On the contrary if this area is large, then it means that the system is far from the top left corner so it's not a great model.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer. It really helped. I accept the answer.